# Cant save models in Ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is what happens when i try to save a model:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:3521
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 ember.js:3521
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba ember.js:3521
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.2.1 ember.js:3521
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.0 ember.js:3521
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:3521
Uncaught #<error> ember.js:73
```

The code that saves the model looks like this:(in a controller)

```
this.get('model').toArray().get('0').save();
```

Even if i save it like this it won't work:

```
this.get('model').save();
```

The model looks like this:

```
App.Imagepost = DS.Model.extend({
    uploader: DS.attr(), // pojo {id:'1', name:'kfir', ...}
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    desc: DS.attr('string'),
    tags: DS.attr(),// array ['#good', '#bad', '#fun', ...]
    pics: DS.attr(), // array of objects
    comments: DS.attr() // array of objects
});
```

I just try to save a fixture data model without even touching it.
Reading the model works fine my template renders perfectly but when i try to save i get this:

```
Uncaught #<error>
```

I tried to debug and seems like it breaks here:

```
if (content) { content.removeArrayObserver(this); }
```

line 25875 in Ember source, full context:

```
  /**
    Invoked when the content property is about to change. Notifies observers that the
    entire array content will change.

    @private
    @method _contentWillChange
  */
  _contentWillChange: Ember.beforeObserver('content', function() {
    var content = this.get('content');

    if (content) { content.removeArrayObserver(this); }
    var len = content ? get(content, 'length') : 0;
    this.arrayWillChange(content, 0, len);
  }),
```

It is untouched JSON! why Ember-data can't save it?
**Ember data is killing me spending 3 days just on workarounds and infinite bugs related to it**

**EDIT:**
The comments are right the problem is that Ember-data doesnt save arrays which breaks my template with this error.

Where can i find the code which Ember data uses to save stuff? I want to modify it so arrays will be saved

Shall i forfeit and acknolwedge that Ember data is an untamed beast and drop my mongo backend in favor of mysql so Ember data will be happy once again

Comment: The second piece of code is the way to save your model - `this.get('model').save()`.  But you havent included enough context to know what the problem might be. Are you creating a new model and saving it or are you updating a model? If using ember data what server/database are you using? Your model seems a bit off too. Dont think you should be using arrays in there. Instead each one should be a separate model, ie tags is a model, pics is a model, and then they have a relationship to your model. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_defining-relationships

Comment: looking again uplaoder, your first model attribute looks like it should also be a separate model.

Comment: What's the model, is it a collection? or a single record?  You don't have to use Ember Data, I've done quite a few projects with just POJO's or Ember Objects...

Comment: This usually happens when your templates have mismatched html tags. Review the templates on which you were working on most recently.

Comment: @Craicerjack the model is actually a collection model so i wanted to save just the first. kingpin2k yea a collection isnt it alot of work to make ember objects to update? Hrishi the weird part is that before saving the template works and after saving the template cant show arrays anymore so tags and pics are ommited from the template

Comment: @kingpin2k look above

Comment: @kfir - havent come across a 'collection model' in ember before - all data done like this would be multiple models related to each other and accessed as such. ie hasMany and belongsTo. As ember do on their site with posts and comments example

Comment: @Craicerjack Its just that I really wanted to use embedded objects cause my backend uses them and it works very well in my design, I guess I'll tweak my server to fake mysql-like queries even though it uses Mongo as backend

Comment: Dont change it on my account. Im new to it all myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use Ember-data for embedded. too broken.
Try Ember-model